# Any AWS service to store the configs used by lambda or ec2 hosts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Does AWS provides any service for storing all the configs and we can get this config by just making a call to it? Here the config can be version controlled or available with less latency and so on?

Eg. I want to use some configs from the lambda function which I can easily change without changing the lambda function.

Comment: you can use cloud formation template

Comment: Cloudformation template is for version control. But what AWS resource for config?

Comment: dynamo db you can use

Comment: environment variables would come to my mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store**. It provides a centralized store to manage configuration data such as database strings, secrets or credentials.
https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/#Parameter_Store

Answer (score 2):

[DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is typically used for that purpose. The latency for a single [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) request is typically around 5ms, and you can cache the results client-side to reduce the latency even further and to avoid a read io ever time.